# Symfony 6 Persisting Objects to the Database

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Here is the error message when displaying: "An exception occurred while executing a query: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'done' cannot be null"

I don't understand why this error occurs when everything seems very normal.

Here's my DefaultController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Todo;
use App\Form\TodoType;
use Doctrine\Persistence\ManagerRegistry;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;

class DefaultController extends AbstractController {
    #[Route('/', name:'index')]
    public function index(Request $request, ManagerRegistry $mr) {
       $todo = new Todo();
       $todoForm = $this->createForm(TodoType::class, $todo);
       $todoForm->handleRequest($request);
    //    dd($todoForm);

       if($todoForm->isSubmitted() && $todoForm->isValid() ){
           $todo->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
           $entityManager = $mr->getManager();
           $entityManager->persist($todo);
           $entityManager->flush();


       }
       
       return $this->render('./page1.html.twig',
       ['form'=>$todoForm->createView()]
    );
       
    }
}
```

Here is the code of my entity class todo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\TodoRepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: TodoRepository::class)]
class Todo
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'string', length: 255)]
    private $content;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean', options:["default" => false])]
    private $done;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'datetime' , options:["default" => "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"])]
    private $createdAt;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getContent(): ?string
    {
        return $this->content;
    }

    public function setContent(string $content): self
    {
        $this->content = $content;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getDone(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->done;
    }

    public function setDone(bool $done): self
    {
        $this->done = $done;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getCreatedAt(): ?\DateTimeInterface
    {
        return $this->createdAt;
    }

    public function setCreatedAt(\DateTimeInterface $createdAt): self
    {
        $this->createdAt = $createdAt;

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Here is my TodoType form:

```
<?php

namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Todo;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class TodoType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options): void
    {
        $builder
            ->add('content')
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver): void
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Todo::class,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I tried another method by injecting the EntityManagerInterface service in my controller, unfortunately. I get the same error message. Need help please.

Comment: Do you have a database service set up and running? if so, what is it? MySQL? MariaDB? PostgreSQL? Do you have the `.env` var setup properly? Do you have the driver set up?

Comment: DATABASE_URL="mysql://root:GGNgroup123456+@127.0.0.1:3306/doctrine2?serverVersion=8.0.28"

Comment: If you added `options:["default" => false]` afterwards, did you run a schema update and cache clear? Also you can try initialising the property like this: `private $done = false;`

Comment: I tried clearing the cache, nothing special. Still the same error message.

Comment: @HervéSonkeng, and what about initialising the property?

Comment: @Bossman it works perfectly.it works perfectly. Thank you very much.  What is the use of the option pass as a parameter options:["default" => false]? Explain me.

Comment: @HervéSonkeng It is for the [database schema](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_schema), so it sets it in MySQL (for example, depending on what you use). Not sure why that didn't work for you, multiple reasons why it might not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of initialising your property withing the ORM you can do it underneath

```
#[ORM\Column(type: 'boolean')]
    private $done = false;
```

Or you could do it as soon as you submit the form, by any means when you submit the form it sets the done value to false. However this method isn't practical.

```
if($todoForm->isSubmitted() && $todoForm->isValid() ){
       $todo->setCreatedAt(new \DateTime());
       $todo->setDone(0); // Sets the value to false as soon as the form is submitted
       $entityManager = $mr->getManager();
       $entityManager->persist($todo);
       $entityManager->flush();
```